# Invalid provisioning profile when creating Notification Extension Service using OneSignal in Xamarin Project

Tags: ios, xamarin, notifications, onesignal

Guys. We're having an bundle id issue in Xamarin (iOS). Our bundle id has only two strings (com.DOMAIN). We want to use "Notification Extension Service", but when we try to build it is throwing invalid provisioning profile. Does it have some solution? Because we can't modify our Bundle ID anymore :( OR is it possible?

Comment: Did it works fine before you use  "Notification Extension Service"?

Comment: It is working, but not properly. Most times the default inFocusDisplaying (InAppAlert) isn't working. The notification appears as inFocusDisplaying was set to (Notification) and the "click" on the notification doesn't trigger OneSignal methods.